# Observing contact changes

Tags: swift, cncontactstore

Hi I have tried to observe the changes in the contacts list.
In the View controller i set the notification for receive the event for contacts change.

```
class TestChangeContatct: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(addressBookDidChange),
            name: NSNotification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange,
            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func addressBookDidChange(notification: NSNotification){
        print("notification: \(notification)")
    }

}
```

But the addressBookDidChange is never called, anyone know why?
From Apple:

> **Contacts Changed Notifications** 
>   After a save is successfully executed,
>   the contact store posts a CNContactStoreDidChange notification to the
>   default notification center. If you cache any Contacts framework
>   objects you need to refetch those objects, either by their
>   identifiers, or with the predicates that were used to originally fetch
>   them, and then release the cached objects. Note that cached objects
>   are stale, but not invalid.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts

Comment: The post should be sent from the system, when a contact is changeed

Comment: How are you testing this? Can you describe specific steps so one can duplicate this?

Comment: sure the step are:
1) open the test app with that viewcontroller
2) press home
3) open the phone contact list, and add new one